# PLS-00103: end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static member constructor map

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am error while execute the below codes,

Here is my code:

```
create member function for not instantiable not final type

create or replace type the_type as object 
(a1         xxx(50),
 a2         number(3), -- minutes
 a3             date,
member function fone return number,
member function ftwo (pString1 varchar2, pString2 varchar2) return integer)
not instantiable not final




create or replace type body the_type as
member function fone return number is
begin
return null;
end fone;

member function ftwo (pString1 varchar2, pString2 varchar2) return integer is
v_1 integer;
begin
    if INSTR(pString2,pString1) != 0 then
        v_1 := 1;
    else
        v_1 := 0;
    end if;
    return v1;
end ftwo ;
```

/

This is the error message

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of
>   the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding
>   static    member constructor map

Comment: Inconsistent tags. <plsql> is for <oracle>, not <sql-server>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `END` keyword:

```
create or replace type body the_type as
member function fone return number is
begin
return null;
end fone;

member function ftwo (pString1 varchar2, pString2 varchar2) return integer is
v_1 integer;
begin
    if INSTR(pString2,pString1) != 0 then
        v_1 := 1;
    else
        v_1 := 0;
    end if;
    return v_1; -- also this should be "v_1", not "v1"
end ftwo ;
end; -- this one
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f383df0fd3289bf5409fa303ff8efa4)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you! you really have sharp eyes.
BTW, when i implement ftwo in query. It doesnt work as I expect.
ftwo(the_name_of_the_table.the_column, 'something i wanna search')
It always return 0.

Comment: That must be different error with an altogether different questions. Please ask a different questions for different issues to avoid the mess. For now, I have solved your compilation issue. Please accept this answer and ask another question with a description.